# How to catch multiple exceptions on SaveChanges() or is it possible?

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I get an XML file(from an infopath form), create an object and insert that object into the DB.  Im using a C# webservice to do this parsing and it returns true if successful and currently it returns the exception message if the SaveChanges() fails.  The main exceptions I'd like to return are the DbEntityValidationExceptions as I'll handle other exceptions differently.  Some of the columns have max lengths so is the field exceeds that I want to return the field name that they need to edit. Can I catch all the DbEntityValidationException for all fields that failed or does entity only throw the first exception and then rollback the transaction?  With 200 fields it'd be nice to tell the user which fields they need to change versus the first field and then continue to fail as they fix the single exception each time.

If it is not possible my proposed solution below is irrelevant and should be removed. If it is possible to return all the Exceptions, what am I doing wrong?

```
         exceptionList = new List<string>();
         try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.GetType() == new DbEntityValidationException().GetType())
                {
                    DbEntityValidationException eValidEx = (DbEntityValidationException) ex;
                    foreach (DbEntityValidationResult vResult in eValidEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (DbValidationError vError in vResult.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            exceptionList.Add(vError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    result = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    exceptionList.Add("Unknown. " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need custom exception which inherit Exception. In this exception you have property for example Errors. This property will be message collection.

When you are trying to save  changes, you should know what kind of fields you are expecting. You should define in other class boundaries of the fields(example Price->decimal, mandatory, maxValue and so on) On save you should check the boundaries if one of them is not true you should add message string in Errors of the custom exception(example Price is not decimal field)

On the end if the Errors.Count > 0 thorw the CustomException. You should override the message property in the CustomException -> loop all the Errors and return the text of all of them. At the end you need only customException.Message and you will have all the problems shown to the user.

I Hope this helps.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to implement your solution a little easier by overriding the 'ValidateEntity' method and using data annotations in the class. Dynamically enumurating an objects members and validating against data annotations would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

So when you catch an exception like that, you'll only catch the first exception. Java doesn't let you keep going on when you have a bunch of Exceptions and to catch all of them.

What you could do is put the entire thing in a while loop that keeps going until you've saved all of the changes. Make sure in the try{} block that you iterate through each field instead of just trying the first field again and again.

Comment: Thanks for your response User... I'm actually using C#, however I do understand your comment. (editted question to note framework)  I currently have 22 tables with about 10 columns each. For now I add all of the tables, then call a single SaveChanges(). In your iterative solution, how would you iterates through all entities while skipping the exceptions that you've already hit?  Also, I do not want incomplete records in the db for reporting, so if I do iterate through all fields until the end and catch all exceptions, then is there a better way than reverting to an older context?